# Plotly - unused arguments error - appears inconsistent

Tags: r, plotly

I am  creating a Rmarkdown document that contains a number of plots created with plotly.

I cannot figure out why one of my plots is throwing an 'unused arguments' error, as the plot I create before it, which using the same arguments but a different subset of data, works fine. I want to use these 2 plots in a subplot.

Here's what I've got:

```
    df_subset1_p <- 
      plot_ly(df_subset1, x = ~Month, y = ~data.percent, width = 800, height = 500) %>%
      add_lines(color = ~cat) %>%
      layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, margin = m)

    df_subset2_p <- 
      plotly(df_subset2, x = ~Month, y = ~data.percent, width = 800, height = 500) %>%
      add_lines(color = ~cat) %>%
      layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, margin = m)
```

Before I can even call the subplot, df_subset2_p throws the error:

```
Error in plotly(df_subset2, x = ~Month, y = ~data.percent, : unused arguments (x = ~Month, y = ~data.percent, width = 800, height = 500)
```

I get the error on the 2nd plot, even if I try to run it first. The error reproduces if I just run the script and not the RMarkdown.

The structure of the dataframes looks fine to me.  Month is a factor and data.percent is numeric for both.

I tried removing width, height and layout options, same error.

The error reproduces if I run the script without Rmarkdown.

I haven't found this exact problem reported by others on SO, though there are some similar complaints suggesting a compatibility issue between plotly and ggplot (older versions) or that another loaded package is using the same function name. But I don't see how this can be the case here, since I have many previous plots in the notebook that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`df_subset2_p <- 
      plotly([...])`

should be:

`df_subset2_p <- 
      plot_ly([...])`

Edit: 
See `?plotly` and `?plot_ly`

Answer (score -1):

The error was all in the typo. (Sighs.)

`plot_ly` initiates a plotly visualization, whereas `plotly` is a deprecated function previously used to store plotly account credentials.

Always use `plot_ly`.

Comment: This is not true, I am using plot_ly and I am having the same error